# How to change safari settings through Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, safari, applescript

I am trying to automate a few steps needed for my script to work properly and I was trying to find out if there are any ways to change some settings for Safari in a Mac through the terminal itself.

Mainly I am trying to enable javascript, block popups and always allow a certain a plugin that I have installed.

I would like a solution by either shell script or apple script or some other way also.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I am using com.apple.Safari.plist to change values.
Refer my other question [on how to edit plists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42645351/7504076)